# javascript mvc framework for mobile developement

Tags: javascript, node.js

To develop web application I have different design for phones and tablet. 
I need a MVC framework that will render a view according to device (mobile or tablet).

I need a framework for node.js to render view according to user agent. this web application will be wrapped into phone app with phonegap.

Can you advice?

Comment: You don't need a specific framework to use MVC, and most "MVC frameworks" have their own flavor of MVC that might not even match with the original idea. You're better off picking a good framework and exercising good design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too general. What you are asking basically depends on the server-side. Based on the `User-Agent` header, server-side will decide which views to render.

Then, in the client-side you have various of choices
jQuery Mobile + Backbone
jQuery Mobile + Angular
....

or jQuery Mobile alone

or Sencha Touch as `fauverism` mentioned

Basically, any normal client-side JS MVC framework will work in your case

*Updated according to the comment*
For nodejs, again there are several choices

If you want to have total control, I suggest you use http://expressjs.com/
In case you want to get something done fast and easy, pick any other MVC frameworks in the nodejs world such as

- http://sailsjs.org/#!
- http://compoundjs.com/docs.html
- http://tower.github.io/

If you want to use a middleware to detect mobile browsers, use this https://github.com/3rd-Eden/useragent

Comment: I need a framework for node.js to render view according to user agent.   this web application will be wrapped to phone app with phonegap